# Python FFT - Output fft is the same as input function?

Tags: python, math, fft

I am trying to perform an FFT on data from a simulation that has an oscilating shape. When I run the scipy FFT, the output is the same as the input and I can't figure out why. My code is below:

```
tstart = 7.5000000000039813e-2
rho = 0.80272956E-04
V = 4773.706375394508
Aref = 0.203911
Pnondim = 0.5 * rho * V**2 * Aref

df1 = pd.read_csv('screenP.csv')
P1 = -np.array(df1[:])/Pnondim
CT = 1.52
Ax1 = P1 + CT
steps1 = len(P1)
dt1 = 2e-7
tend1 = tstart + steps1*dt1
t1 = np.linspace(tstart,tend1,steps1) * 1000
plt.plot(t1,Ax1)
plt.show()

X = fftpack.rfft(Ax1)
freq = fftpack.rfftfreq(len(Ax1), dt1)

plt.plot(freq, np.abs(X))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), plt.ylabel('Power')
plt.show()
```

where screenP is data output from a CFD solver.
The original curve and the fft output are shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iPa8.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Eja9.png

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example shows sinusoid for source `a` and peak for fourier result.

```
from scipy.fftpack import rfft
import math, numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [math.sin(i/5) for i in range(100)]
plt.plot(a)
plt.show()
fu = rfft(a)
plt.plot(numpy.abs(fu))
plt.show()
```

What code creates your first and second picture? Please show us reproducible example.

Result of `rfft` might overwrite source array if parameter `overwrite_x`  is set, but it's default value is `False`

Comment: Since you imported numpy, why not `a = np.sin(np.arange(100)/5)`?

Comment: @Stef I have not experience with numpy, just made something working.

Comment: I tried doing this, however, using fft instead of rfft doesn't solve the issue. I have edited my intial question to include the full code for the two curves, although I can't include the code of how the original is produced as it was output from a CFD solver.

Comment: Side note (from scipy docs): *This submodule is now considered legacy, new code should use [scipy.fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fft.html#module-scipy.fft).*

Answer (score 1):

I was facing identical issue with np.fft.fft (derived from scipy.fft).
The issue was with the shape of input. I was providing python lists as input initially, then tried with numpy array of shape (len(input),1).
Finally, when I used numpy array of shape (len(input),) it worked.